# Codeigniter issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

**Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->model('Home_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->Home_model->getcategory(); 
        $this->load->view('userheader', $data); 
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getcategory()
    {           
        $this->db->select('id, cat_value, cat_title','isactive');
        $query = $this->db->get('js_job_categories');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**Views**

I include the header and footer 
same content displaying again below footer

In top of the header it does not display the query result
how can solve the problem..

Comment: Show how you have done implementation in the view. Its hard to guess why you cannot display query result.

Comment: Result are displaying.. the header repeats for twice.i include the header at top after.printed query result are shown below the footer the header repeats a twice

Comment: would still be better if you can post your view. `userheader.php` and `welcome_message.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the header in both the welcome_message and the userheader view? Call both views after you get data for $data['query']

```
$this->load->helper('url'); 
$this->load->model('Home_model');
$data['query'] = $this->Home_model->getcategory(); 

$this->load->view('welcome_message');
$this->load->view('userheader', $data);
```

do you need to include $data for the welcome_message view? Also when you pass $data to the view you can now access the values by just $query, not $data['query']

Comment: No i found the solution for this issue.Thanks for ur help.. dasper

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you doesn't attach the **Views/welcome_message.php** 
you can display the query request like this

```
<?php
```

`//header`

```
echo '<br/>';

var_dump($query);

echo '<br/>';

//footer
?>
```